# MDL2 Info Symbol

Tags: xaml, fonts, assets

Microsoft uses a specific symbol for informationial purposes it is a circle with the letter i inside [Image of the Symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUzcO.png). I looked at every resource about the Segoe MDL2 Assets Font but did not find that symbol. Does anyone know if this symbol is part of the font or is it just another image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symbol code point is `E946`.

---

The following WPF code snippet creates an `IEnumerable<int>` that contains all symbol code points in `Segoe MDL2 Assets`.

```
var typeface = new Typeface(
    new FontFamily("Segoe MDL2 Assets"),
    FontStyles.Normal, FontWeights.Normal, FontStretches.Normal);

GlyphTypeface glyphTypeface;
typeface.TryGetGlyphTypeface(out glyphTypeface);

var codePoints = glyphTypeface.CharacterToGlyphMap.Keys.Where(c => c > 0x20);
```

You can easily visualize this collection by setting `DataContext = codePoints` and writing an ItemsControls like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock
                    Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Text="{Binding StringFormat={}{0:X4}}"/>
                <TextBlock
                    Margin="2" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="24"
                    Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource CodePointConverter}}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

with this CodePointConverter class:

```
public class CodePointConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new string((char)(int)value, 1);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx, I will try that when I come home. Do you have any resource where really any symbol is listed?

Comment: There is the [Symbol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.symbol) enum and [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj841126.aspx).