# C# Custom Font Values interpreted as String instead of Single Value

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using a Custom Font to display Icons in my WPF application. I wrote a little demo application to present me the icon alongside with the corresponding "Character".

Unfortunately, C# does not interpret the resulting string of my iterations as a single character, but as string.

The code:

```
 private string _BaseString = "&#xE";
        public IconsPane()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitIcons();
        }

        private void InitIcons()
        {

            string[] hex = new string[16] { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" };

            string output = "";
            foreach (string a in hex)
            {
                foreach (string b in hex)
                {
                    foreach (string c in hex)
                    {
                        output = a + b + c;
                        CreateIcon(output);
                    }
                }

            }

        }

        private void CreateIcon(string output)
        {
            StackPanel st = new StackPanel();
            st.Margin = new Thickness(5);

            Button ILabel = new Button();
            ILabel.Style = (Style)FindResource("ContentButtonPlain");
            ILabel.Content = _BaseString + output + ";";

            TextBox IDesc = new TextBox();
            IDesc.Text = (string)ILabel.Content;
            IDesc.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;

            st.Children.Add(ILabel);
            st.Children.Add(IDesc);

            IconDashboard.Children.Add(st);

        }
```

Output:
[image]

Instead I would like to have each Icon that is behind that string:

Expected Output:

[image]

The screenshot of the expected output is taken from XAML code in the designer:

```
<Button Margin="5 0 5 0"
                                                        Style="{StaticResource ContentButtonPlain}"
                                                        Content="&#xE3e2;" />
```

In this case, the icon is recognised in the correct way.

Comment: In C#, unicode character escape sequences are written as `\uXXXX` instead of `&#xXXXX;` which is used in XML/XAML.

Comment: Well, \u didn't really help. Neither did (char)xxx help, I need to be able to exactly show &#xEXXX; and the icon itself. My main problem is to understand how I can make out of a+b+c the correct \u character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to create all symbols in range `E000` to `EFFF`. You could do it like this:

```
foreach (char symbolChar in Enumerable.Range(0xE000, 0x1000))
{
    var symbolString = new string(symbolChar, 1);

    // replace this by your actual code that creates UI elements
    st.Children.Add(new Label { Content = symbolString });
}
```

Besides that you may certainly better use an ItemsControl with an appropriate ItemTemplate to display the symbols, as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34156141/1136211.